# Find value of a children Div ID inside another DIV

Tags: jquery, children

I have a listing of DIVs in my CMS HTML Page where I want to know the value of the ID of a child DIV.

As an example, here is the HTML :-

```
<div class="view" id="views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_3">
  <div class="views-slideshow-cycle">
     <div class="content clearfix">
       <div class="field-item even">
         <div class="jwplayer-video">
            <div id="4ac1a678934a37fd58e86cf0a7d51c79_wrapper">
               <object></object></div>
```

What I need to know is the value of ID of DIV inside of DIV with class=jwplayer-video, which is "4ac1a678934a37fd58e86cf0a7d51c79_wrapper"

What I tried to do is:-

```
$("#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_0").find(".jwplayer-video")
```

or even this

```
$("#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_0").find(".jwplayer-video").attr("id")
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Any help please.

Thanks.

Comment: It may be a typo in the question but the id in the html doesn't match with the id that you are using in javascript
"views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_3" in html while it is 
"views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_0" in javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_3 .jwplayer-video div:first").attr("id");
```

Comment: one could compress the last bit to `div:first`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`$('#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_3').find('div.jwplayer-video').find('div').eq(0).attr('id');`

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yRVqE/) for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_3").find(".jwplayer-video").children().attr('id')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/S6zFZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#views_slideshow_cycle_div_resources-block_0").find(".jwplayer-video").children().attr("id");
```

The .jwplayer-video div does not have an ID. You must go one step deeper.

Also take a look at  the Id in HTML and jQuery

block_0 and block_3

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".jwplayer-video").children().attr("id")
```