# Dragula: get class and id of the dragged item

Tags: typescript, dragula

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39009643/get-id-of-dropped-div-using-dragula-javascript), but it does not work in my code.
I am using `Dragula`, in my `Angular2` application with `Typescript`.

I need to get the id of the element of the draged element.
Here is a part of the typescript class:

```
 constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService) {

    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value) => {
       this.onDrop(value.slice(1));
    });

  }


  private onDrop(args) {
    let [e, el] = args;
    console.log("on Drop");
    console.log(e);
    console.log(el);
  }
```

I know the `el` contains the draged element, but **how can i get the id out of an html element in typescript?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `el` is the dragged element, then its id is `el.id`. That's how the DOM works. If you are dragging an element `<div id="foo">something</div>` and this element is assigned to `el` in your code, then `el.id` will be `"foo"`.

Answer (score 2):

If your html element is derived from an object model, there's a now neater way to obtain the id with dragula v2.0.

By using `[(dragulaModel)]`, you can access the entire object model, including your object's id. For example:

In the html:

```
<div [(dragulaModel)]="listOfItems">
   <div *ngFor="let item of listOfItems">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your Angular service:

```
this.subs.add(
   dragulaService.dropModel().subscribe((value) => {
      // prints the item's id
      console.log(value.item.id);
   })
)
```

The best part of this method is you gain access to all the properties of the dragged item with `value.item` amongst others. See documentation: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula#special-events-for-ng2-dragula

Comment: Who gave this a -1? This helped me after days scourging the internet for an answer as to how to pass a model object.  Granted I'm new to Angular, but his resolved my issue.